# Group by datatable value using linq

Tags: linq, datatable, group-by

I want to use Linq with DataTable to get the following

DataTable content

```
periodstart periodend value
2013-01-01 2013-02-01 10
2013-02-02 2013-03-01 10
2013-03-02 2013-04-01 15
2013-04-02 2013-05-01 20
2013-05-02 2013-06-01 10
2013-06-02 2013-07-02 20
```

Results

```
2013-01-01 2013-03-01 10
2013-03-02 2013-04-01 15
2013-04-02 2013-05-01 20
2013-05-02 2013-06-01 10
2013-06-02 2013-07-02 20
```

Basically I want to group periods by value, but also allow repeating the same value if there is a different grouping for a period in between.

I wanted to go with group by value using min and max value for periods, but that would give me something like

```
2013-01-01 2013-06-01 10
2013-03-02 2013-04-01 15
2013-04-02 2013-07-02 20
```

which is incorrect.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are your periods always contiguous and non-overlapping? Are they always ordered? (So can we just group by "consecutive periods with the same value"?)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes periods are contiguous and non-overlapping!

Comment: And already ordered? Presumably you could do that as a first step separately...

Answer (score 0):

(Adding a separate answer as my now-deleted one is wrong.)

It sounds like you just need to iterate over all rows, keeping a group going until the value part changes, and then taking the start of the first element and the end of the last element. So you could do something like this as an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupByContiguous<T, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> groupSelector)
{
    List<T> currentGroup = new List<T>();
    T groupKey = default(T);
    // This could be passed in as a parameter
    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        groupKey = groupSelector(iterator.Current);
        currentGroup.Add(iterator.Current);
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var item = iterator.Current;
            var key = groupSelector(item);
            if (!comparer.Equals(groupKey, key))
            {
                yield return currentGroup.Select(x => x);
                currentGroup = new List<T>();
                groupKey = key;
            }
            currentGroup.Add(item);
        }            
    }
    // Trailing group
    yield return currentGroup.Select(x => x);
}
```

Then use this as:

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
                 .GroupByContiguous(row => row.Field<int>("value"))
                 .Select(g => new { 
                     Value = g.Key,
                     EarliestStart = g.First().Field<DateTime>("periodstart"),
                     LatestEnd = g.Last().Field<DateTime>("periodend")
                 });
```